# How do I store card game states in a NodeJS app hosted on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, card-game, game-state

I have a turn based card game node app, and in development env I store all game states in memory (1 object per "game" in a big parent object) since these objects are constantly changing and since I need really fast access to them. I'm new to Heroku and I have just deployed my first website, and saving in memory doesn't seem to work due to multiple processes, plus there's an automatic server restart every 24 hours.

1. What options do I have to save game states in Heroku or any other similar service?
2. Is there a way I can overcome this automatic server restart?
3. Should I use another host, instead? If so, what should I be looking for?

Comment: Presumably you looked at Heroku's database or Redis add-ons, which offer ways to share data between instances and persist data across instance restarts?

Comment: I meant to ask if storing such a "big" value would be an acceptable thing to do (I have no experience with Redis), but i will figure this out myself. Thanks!

Comment: If you find a way that works for you, be sure to post it as an Answer below.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
Actually i'm still struggling to find a solution that suits me.
A games[gameID] object (which is the core of the game) always being modified, with every player action and every calculation (almost). Each player has a reference to that object that lives in memory and until now there was only 1 process in 1 machine. I can't see how i can use Redis as a solution :(

Comment: What specific obstacle do you perceive that we can help you overcome?

Comment: The object representing the game must be always available for getting and setting data by the server and the players/sockets from the moment it's created until it's gone (end of game).
It means that i can't store this object externally, and then get (for a new player/socket) a COPY of it instead of a REFERENCE, and then modify the copy instead of the reference.
That's the obstacle.

Comment: Right now with one process it works fine, but i want to horizontal scale my app so now i have this problem...

Comment: You can't have two processes simultaneously manipulating a reference, for obvious reasons. What you can do is have one process take ownership of it (eg. setting a flag), take a copy, modify the copy, write it back, then release the ownership for the next process to use.